# The type or namespace [...] could not be found (no overloaded target framework)

Tags: c#, xna, visual-c#-express-2010

> The type or namespace name 'Highscores2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've seen several threads on here with similar "type or namespace could not be found" problems, but the only root-cause was to make sure that the 'missing' namespace was also targeting the same framework.

In my particular case, "Target framework" is not set (and is even grayed out) in the properties of all of the projects, so that doesn't appear to be the issue.

The "using Highscores2;" is spelled correctly (copy/pasted from the namespace declaration) and the build order appears to be correct.

Additionally, the Highscores2 project builds fine on its own, and in a demo solution that came with the project, that solution actually builds just fine.

What other types of things (that I'm missing) can cause the "type or namespace could not be found" error?

Comment: Probably a silly question, but do you have a project or DLL reference to `Highscores2`?

Comment: @Laurence I have Highscores2 added as a project in the solution. Does that answer the question you're asking?

Comment: You can have it as a project in the solution, but if you are trying to access it from another project that one must have a reference. You can open the target project's properties and check the "References" tab, and you should see an Add button. Here is the MSDN page if it helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: That appears to have solved it! :D Was incorrectly assuming that adding the project as a dependency would do that automatically, but that isn't the case at all.  Can you add this as an answer so I can accept? Thanks for the fix!

Comment: Of course! I'm glad that helped, and trust me I've done that a few too many times as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it as a project in the solution, but if you are trying to access it from another project that one must have a reference. You can open the target project's properties and check the "References" tab, and you should see an Add button.

Here is the MSDN page if it helps: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've had a problem with this before with multiple projects. When I added a reference to the second project, in this case the one referencing HighScore2.dll, it was pointed to the /release build of the dll. However, in Debug /release isn't built, and so it couldn't find it. This may be a longshot, but if this is the case you can open up the csproj with notepad and edit the path for the assembly to use $(Configuration) in the path to point to the correct build configuration.